# Figure Problem. it goes automatically to background

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, positioning

I have code like this:

```
\subsection{heading1}
blah blah
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
. . .
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{..}
\caption{title}
\end{figure}
something...
\subsection{heading2}
\subsection{heading3}
```

when I am running the code I see the picture goes to background of the text and next subsection and even "caption" doesn't care about the figure.
I tried the picture without putting in figure format, same result came out :/

thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: presumably you have specified that the size of the tikzpicture is much smaller than the actual extent of the drawing, but as you have not shown any code relevant to the problem it's hard to help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh yesss I had "overlay" feature, having removed it my problem solved.  thanksss

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to an improper key in the user's input (not shown in the question).

Comment: @egreg yeah.  sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you have specified that the size of the tikzpicture is much smaller than the actual extent of the drawing. (Actually confirmed in comments `overlay` was used which effectively specifies that the picture has size zero height hand width).